# How can I select "AccountTeamMember" in the Summarized Object in create field?

Tags: account, roll-up-summary, account-teams

I'm trying the create a Roll Up Summary Field that use the TeamMemberRole, but I can't see the name of the Object in the options (see the pic).

Somebody told me that I have to create a field type Master Detail Relationship to do it...But is there another way to do it without creating a useless field?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship between Account Team Member and Account is a Lookup, and is not eligible for rollups.

Because this is a standard object, you cannot make it a master-detail child of another object, so creating a roll-up-able relationship is not a possibility.

You'll need to use your own automation, or a product like [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or [Apex Rollup](https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-rollup/).

Answer (score 0):

What I did: I've installed "Roll Up Helper" in AppExchange and its works!